# A powered by B equals C - how to get A

Tags: logarithms

Very stupid question, I know :)

A powered by B equals C.
If I know `A` and `B`, it's easy to compute `C`

If I know `A` and `C`, it's also not so hard just by using logarithms

But what if I have `B` and `C`, how to get `A`?

If you could give an example is some JS, C or Python, that would really help me understand things.

Thank you so much!

Comment: if $x^2=4$, then $x= \sqrt 4$

Comment: If $a,b>0$, then $a^b=e^{b \ln a}$.

Comment: In python it would be something like `A = C ** (1 / B)`

Comment: Of course, ‍♂️, thank you :)